# Re-map copy & paste

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using an Apple Magic Keyboard and would like to remap the keyboard shortcuts to be more apple like.

For example:

Command + C for copy
Command + V for paste

etc.

What is the best way to accomplish this?